# Got error for console application. An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, console-application

I'm trying to following this to query Team Foundation Server:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb130306.aspx

Here is what I have

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(
   new Uri("http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection"));
    WorkItemStore workItemStore = (WorkItemStore)tpc.GetService   (typeof(WorkItemStore));

            // Run a query.
            WorkItemCollection queryResults = workItemStore.Query(
               "Select [State], [Title] " +
               "From WorkItems " );

            // Run a saved query.
            QueryHierarchy queryRoot = workItemStore.Projects[0].QueryHierarchy;
            QueryFolder folder = (QueryFolder)queryRoot["Shared Queries"];
            QueryDefinition query = (QueryDefinition)folder["Active Bugs"];
            queryResults = workItemStore.Query(query.QueryText);
        //}
```

I get the error:

```
 An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'   occurred in Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.dll

Additional information: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
```

I added a catch exception and I get this error:

```
Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: index.
```

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: QueryHierarchy queryRoot = workItemStore.Projects[0].QueryHierarchy;

Comment: `workItemStore.Projects[0]` assumes that there is a project. Maybe there are no projects?

Comment: Is there a way to check this? Sorry I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: Yes, check if `workItemStore.Projects.Count` equals 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your workItemStore.Projects must be empty or null.